# Как в Pandas выбрать данные из DataFrame по условию "in np.array"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

У меня есть примерно такой набор данных, только в сотни тысяч строк:

```
data = [{'name': 'name1', 'launch_id': 5},\
        {'name': 'name2', 'launch_id': 6},\
        {'name': 'name2', 'launch_id': 7},\
        {'name': 'name3', 'launch_id': 8}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Будет:

```
  | launch_id | name
---------------------
0   5           name1
1   6           name2
2   7           name2
3   8           name3
```

Хочу выбрать из него некоторые строки, с `launch_id` полученными из другого большого DataFrame. Необходимые `launch_id` я сохранил в `np.array` с названием `simple`:

```
simple = np.array([5, 8])
```

Теперь хочется получить такой результат:

```
  | launch_id | name
---------------------
0   5           name1
3   8           name3
```

Если бы я писал SQL запрос, то написал бы что-то `where launch_id in simple`.

Как можно получить аналогичный результат в Pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [16]: df.query("launch_id in @simple")
Out[16]:
   launch_id   name
0          5  name1
3          8  name3
```

или

```
In [18]: df[df['launch_id'].isin(simple)]
Out[18]:
   launch_id   name
0          5  name1
3          8  name3
```

[Pandas: comparison with SQL ...](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html)

---

PS Apache Spark SQL поддерживает ANSI SQL и соответственно позволяет напрямую писать SQL запросы.

Comment: Это я так могу любой `SQL` запрос туда запихнуть?

Comment: @Viktorov, нет, не любой и в Pandas иногда это будет сильно отличаться от SQL. Советую [ознакомиться](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html)

Comment: а какой из пердложенных вариантов более "общепринят" ?)  если на такой вопрос вообще можно ответить)

Comment: @Viktorov, лично я предпочитаю первый вариант по двум причинам - легче читается и быстрее работает (в большинстве случаев)